# Why does memchr() take a void pointer as input?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I'm currently reprogramming some C libraries. So my question is: Why does `memchr` take an `const void *s` pointer and not simply an character pointer?

I see that you could probably search for other stuff, but the function is literally called *memchr* so why use a void pointer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: mem chr, memory (bin) char - first pointer can be any type (`char *`, `unsigned char *`) and no need to cast type.

Comment: A lot of the standard lib functions have bad names for historial reasons. For example `getchar` _clearly_ gets an `int` and not a `char`, right?

Comment: `memchr(&mystruct,0,20)` would cause a compiler warning with `char*`. Even `uint8_t a[20]={0}; /*some code here*/ memchr(a,0,20);` would cause one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C’s early development involved a fair amount of treating things as individual bytes and allowing programmers access to the bytes that represented objects. The name `memchr` reflects that history and cannot readily be changed now.

`void` was added to the language to provide a type that represents, in a sense, “something is there, but this is flexible.” The first parameter to `memchr` has type `const void *` because the routine may be used to search for a byte in any type of object, not necessary an object that is primarily an array of characters.

Comment: `memchr` is probably one of the least bad offenders there: it searches a char (`chr`) in a memory buffer (`mem`). The only part that's unclear is why `c` is typed as an `int` when it must be an unsigned char, but I guess that was one of those things common to early C? Though the size limit is a `size_t` which is pretty modern.

Comment: @Masklinn: With the second parameter declared `int` and the C standard also requiring `void *` and `char *` to have the same representation, the modern declaration `void *memchr(const void *, int, size_t)` is compatible with calls in old source code that might be using a declaration `void *memchr()`, since the default argument promotions will promote a `char` for the second argument to `int`. I am not sure that explains it, since I do not have the history of `memchr` at hand, and the `size_t` could also be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same reason why other functions declared in `string.h` use `void*`: to avoid a cast.

Maybe you're right, the name is misleading, especially considering its it's part of `string.h`. Then again, so is `memmove`, `memcmp`, `memset`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Before the `void` data type was introduced in the 1989 standard (`-std=c89`), functions like `memchr()` used to take `const char *`, because that was the closest thing to a *generic* pointer at the time.

If `const char *` was present today, you will need to cast from `x *` to `const char *`.

You can also understand this using analogy:

- `strcpy()` -> string copy
- `memcpy()` -> memory (binary) copy